Reproducible random numbers in pgfmath and graphs
For a project, I want to experiment with manipulating pseudo-random numbers and create some functions that can reference the n-th generated number at any time. According to an earlier post "TikZ for reproducible hex random numbers" I have started out there by resetting the generator's seed to some predictable value depending on the index, so the next number is always the same:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ ]{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{rng}{1} {
  \pgfmathsetseed{#1 + \time}
  \pgfmathrnd \pgfmathresult
}

\begin{document}

\pgfmathparse{rng(5)} % 0.43082 for some index
\pgfmathparse{rng(8)} % 0.51942 for another index
\pgfmathparse{rng(5)} % 0.43802 again, as expected

\end{document}

This method works perfectly well when I the values are displayed in my document like the above. However, when I try to plot these values on a graph, there is no indication of any proper output:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ ]{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{rng}{1} {
  \pgfmathsetseed{#1 + \time}
  \pgfmathrnd \pgfmathresult
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[axis lines = left]
    \addplot [samples = 300]{rng(x)};
  \end{axis} % Produces incorrect graph
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

Instead of a graph, only the text Y8Y81Y6.9621e-1] is displayed throughout the page, and there is additionally a warning that Axis range for axis y is approximately empty; enlarging it (it is [0.69621:0.69621]). I have tried a number of different options and configurations (including only using one output of the function with rng(0) in the graph), but nothing has produced a working graph yet. What's happening here that prevents this from working identically to pgfmathparse?

Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Your issue is that the rng funtion doesn't work when the FPU is turned on. You need to normalise its #1.

Ok, even with loads of normalising I couldn't get this to run :(

who flagged this for closure as 'needs more details or clarity'?!!

The following uses l3fp to actually create the random number instead of pgfmath. It first normalises the input to be a maximum 9 digit integer. Then it sets the seed and calculates the random number. Note that this has side effects as it not only changes the seed used by pgf but the global seed used by the engine. As a result this might change the behaviour of packages which rely on the same seed.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ ]{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\str_new:N \l_neofox_number_str
\cs_new_protected:Npn \neofox_normalise_pgf_number:n #1
  {
    \group_begin:
      \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true, /pgf/fpu/output~format=fixed}
      \pgfmathsetmacro \l_neofox_number_str {#1}
      \str_remove_once:Nn \l_neofox_number_str { . }
      \str_set:Ne \l_neofox_number_str
        { \neofox_strip_leading_zeroes:V \l_neofox_number_str }
      \str_if_empty:NT \l_neofox_number_str
        { \str_set:Nn \l_neofox_number_str { 0 } }
      \str_set:Ne \l_neofox_number_str
        { \str_range:Nnn \l_neofox_number_str { 1 } { 9 } }
      \exp_args:NNNV
    \group_end:
    \cs_set:Npn \pgfmathresult \l_neofox_number_str
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \neofox_strip_leading_zeroes:n { V }
\cs_new:Npn \neofox_strip_leading_zeroes:n #1
  {
    \__neofox_strip_leading_zeroes:w
      \s_stop #1
      \q_stop \__neofox_strip_leading_zeroes:w
      \s_stop 0 
      \q_stop \__neofox_strip_leading_zeroes_done:w
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__neofox_strip_leading_zeroes:w #1 \s_stop 0 #2 \q_stop #3
  { #3 #1 \s_stop #2 \q_stop #3 }
\cs_new:Npn \__neofox_strip_leading_zeroes_done:w
    \s_stop #1 \q_stop #2 \__neofox_strip_leading_zeroes_done:w
  { #1 }

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{rng}{1}
  {
    \neofox_normalise_pgf_number:n {#1}
    \sys_gset_rand_seed:n { \pgfmathresult + \time }
    \edef \pgfmathresult { \fp_eval:n { rand() } }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[axis lines = left]
    \addplot [samples = 300]{rng(x)};
  \end{axis} % Produces correct graph
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

